# Hamburger menu not showing up on smaller screens for bootstrap 5 navabar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

'I've put in the stylesheets for both bootstrap css and js in the file. It shows up when I retain default colour options but not when I customise the colour.'

'''

```
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">item</a>

        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">item</a>
        </li>



        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">item</a>
        </li>


        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">item</a>
        </li>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

'''

**CSS:** I've added a background colour to the body and also made the nabber the same colour. I've made the text pink and added a green hover to navbar text.#

```
body{
  background-color: #FFE57C;
}
.navbar{
padding-left: 350px;
}

.navbar a:hover{
  color: #FF7CD8;

}

.navbar a {
  color: #FF7CD8;
}
.nav navbar-nav .navbar-center {
  color: ##FF7CD8;
}
```

Comment: The HTML is not properly structured. Remove the `350px` padding-left and use the navbar-light class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try retaining that **navbar-light** class in inside top nav tag, or you can use **navbar-dark** if you want. check the documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/#color-schemes) for more details. this class is associated with showing hamburger icon in bootstrap 5. see the code from bootstrap.css :

```
navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba%280, 0, 0, 0.55%29' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");}
```

but you can change the colors in navbar by adding an **id** for **ul** tag and add the properties for id in style, this way we can tweak the default properties given by the bootstrap. You might be able to achieve what you need by this code, check the code below:

html:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">          
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0" id="nav-list">
                     <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page"href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

css:

```
body{
background-color: #FFE57C;
}
.navbar{
padding-left: 350px;
}

#nav-list a {
color: #FF7CD8;
}
#nav-list a:hover{
color: #FF7CD8;
}
```

for sample i just put 2 list items in navbar.